# Mongo DB Collection schema/metadata export

Tags: python, mongodb, database-metadata, mongodb-compass

as data analyst i access Mongodb whose schema/metadata is not available to me.
With schema/metadata i mean the list of fields and their possible types etc.
in Compass (GUI) i found the possibility to export a collections json schema based on sample data (Menu-->collection-->share schema as json). 
Is there an utility to generate the collection schema/metadata from the whole collection? 
Is there are a programmatic way to do it?In Python even better.

Comment: Here is post with similar question and various ways of getting the schema metadata: [Mongo Schema Diagram or Report](https://community.mongodb.com/t/mongo-schema-diagram-or-report/409)